# Is it possible to run tox directly in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, tox

I have a python project, locally I have setup tox to automate pep8, bandit scans, pytest etc...
Now I 'm asked to move to existing CICD and they have given me a Jenkins file.
I need to add these tox functionality to Jenkins that Jenkins file. Can I directly run these tox commands in the jenkins? Or do I need to look for similar functionality using Jenkins plugins ?

Answer (score 1):

There is literally documentation on the tox website for using it in conjunction with Jenkins - https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/jenkins.html.

Try to use Stackoverflow to get help with a solution that you came up with.

Comment: I'm quite new to this. Are there any examples that I can use for reference? I 'm still facing issues even after following the steps from the above link. I may be missing something trivial.

Comment: At what step do you have troubles?

Comment: That link literally no longer exists.